# Wrap HttpClient service maintaining the typings

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a wrapper for the HttpClient service for making some personalizations. **I don't want to wrap some logic in interceptors**, what I'm looking for is wrapping that service without loosing all the typings.

this is the wrapper:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
  export class RestApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get<T>(url: string, options?) {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, options);
  }
}
```

this is the implementation:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EndpointService } from '../endpoint.service';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RestApiService } from '../rest-api.service';

type Product = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private restApi: RestApiService, private endPoint: EndpointService) {}

  getThings(sku) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('ref', sku);

    return this.restApi.get<Product>(this.endPoint.ratings, {params: params});
  }
}
```

Then in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productService.getThings(this.sku).subscribe(data => {
    data
  });
```

}

In this way `data` is an `ArrayBuffer` because typescript seems to point to this signature of HttpClient:

```
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

But should point to this signature:

```
get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<T>;
```

How can I point to the correct signature?
Also if I pass different options should I point to the correct signature, so if I pass as option `responseType: 'text'` I should point to the correct signature:

```
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<string>;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There is no need to have multiple signatures; That's what options parameter means. You have set the default type 'json' you can change it to i.e. 'text' while function invocation.

Comment: Were you able to write this service? If yes, can you please share your work? It will be helpful